# strings in c programming having garbage value at the end of output

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ char str[3]="ram";
 printf("%s",str);
}
```

output:
ram(garbage value)
the size of the str is 3 and its value having size 3. I expect ra as my answer ofcourse null value will be at end . But i am getting ram(garbage value).
Please some one help me with my problem .

Comment: `char str[3] = "ram";` => `char str[4] = "ram";` => `char str[] = "ram";` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

Comment: make it `char str[]= "ram"`

Comment: printf will look for nul character at the end of string to stop outputting on console ... So thats why you are getting ram + garbage value till nul character is found. This code might give segmentation fault also if no nul character is found

Answer (score 3):

In C a string is a character array with the null character at the end. However in your case, the character array has only 3 elements, so although you are assigning `"ram"` to `char str[3]`, only `'r'`, `'a'` and `'m'` are assigned, `'\0'` is not. Therefore, `printf` cannot tell where the string ends and continues to print garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print the specified number of characters then you can use
"%(no. of characters you want)s"

```
eg printf("%2s"); 
will print ra
```

Comment: That prints a minimum of 2 characters (right justified) and does not stop the garbage characters.  You have to use `”%.3s\n”` to print at most 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string to hold "ram", you need to make its length 4. 3 for the characters plus 1 for the null value.

```
char str[4] = "ram";
printf("%s",str);

//output:
ram
```